# Trigger an envelope's event notification again

Tags: docusignapi

I've set an envelope's event notification to hit my API `foo.com/hook` as soon as it is of status **completed**. However, I had a bug in my API that didn't handle the data well.

Is there any way to trigger the event notification again without editing the envelope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually tell Connect to republish the notification.

See the **Publish** button in the Connect section of the Administration tool.

Or better, see the **Failures** button and section--you can manually request a resend of a notification that failed. (If you have the Require Acknowlegement option on.)

If you're not sure that your Webhook listener will be up 99.999% of the time (with no maintenance windows), then I suggest using an intermediary queuing system. See the [connect- repositories in GitHub](https://github.com/docusign/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=connect-node&type=&language=). They show you how to use AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud to easily and cheaply build a reliable webhook listener for the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

you can set up your connect endpoint configuration to require the web hook to acknowledge the event. This will allow for a retry if the event is not confirmed withing 100 seconds.
"If the Require Acknowledgment option is selected for a Connect Configuration and a publication message fails to be acknowledged within 100 seconds, the message goes back into the queue and the system will retry delivery after a successful acknowledgment is received. If the delivery fails a second time, the message is not returned to the queue for sending until Connect receives a successful acknowledgment and it has been at least 24 hours since the previous retry. There is a maximum of ten retries."
(from https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/connect.htm#Checking2)